# add custom SignIn/Register Api for identity server 4 with Dotnet Core and React js

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, identityserver4, webapi

I am trying to build an application with authentication functionality. My app contains reactjs for front end and Dotnet core as back-end (as it come as a default template in dotnet).  I have multipage registration pages and don't want to create in `.cshtml` file in folder **Areas/Indentity/...** instead all pages will be created in client side (ReactJs).

I am trying to create custom API for login and register and return access-token from my server exactly
like dummy template shipped with dotnet core?

Can any only help me with some documentation or code examples for the reference?
I was looking for reference in Indentity server guide (https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_javascript_client.html)

Comment: Here is a good response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486398/identityserver4-implementation-with-react-spa-and-asp-net-core-backend?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thank you but I had already crossed that link during my research.